# Unable to simulate GPS location on AVD

Tags: android, google-maps, telnet, google-play-services

I basically just want to open Google Maps on an AVD and change the GPS location with telnet and have Google Maps change my displayed location, but I can't get Google Map location to change:

I boot up AVD, I do `adb devices`, I see

```
emulator-5554   device
```

then I do `telnet localhost 5554` and see OK prompt

```
user:~ userName$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'/Users/michaelcas/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
```

then from `~/.emulator_console_auth_token` I copy token `BKLphG9dWG2Isxwb` and authenticate with token

```
user:~ userName$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'/Users/michaelcas/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
auth BKLphG9dWG2Isxwb
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
```

then I open Google Maps on AVD, then set GPS via telnet

```
geo fix -120.65962 35.28275
```

but my location on Google Maps  does not change. Why is that?

Comment: Does it work from [the emulator extended controls](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#extended)?

Comment: I changed the latitude from 30.2828 to 40.2828 and clicked `send` in extended controls, then displayed position changed, then kept jumping around, then map screen turned grey. I am on a mac, so I am going to try this on a pc next.

Comment: Oh, that's probably just simulating the destruction of Earth's satellites, as a precursor to an alien invasion. Gotta test all possible scenarios in mobile app development. :-)